# Need help using python pandas module to create one column from subtracting other two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame called df with two columns that looks something likes this:

```
Column1   Column2
430        550
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
NaN        NaN
453        559
460        650
```

I want to create another column called column 3 that consists of the results column2 - column1. I tried creating a function and then use the apply function in pandas to apply my function to each row from the data frame df. For this, I created the following code:

```
def range(row):

    return (row['column2'])-(row['column1'])

df['column3'] = df.apply(range, axis=1)

df #Calling the data frame to view it
```

However my code is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-604781044dd4> in <module>()
      6 
      7 #Creating column called column3 by using the apply function in pandas to apply the function to each row
----> 8 df['column3'] = df.apply(range, axis=1)
      9 #Setting axis=1 specifier, that means that the application will be done at a row, rather than at column level.
     10 df #Calling the data frame to view it

C:\Users\v761473\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4358                         f, axis,
   4359                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4360                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4361             else:
   4362                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Users\v761473\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4454             try:
   4455                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4456                     results[i] = func(v)
   4457                     keys.append(v.name)
   4458             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-13-604781044dd4> in range(row)
      2 def range(row):
      3     """ Function to calculate the range from """
----> 4     return (row['column2'])-(row['column1'])
      5 
      6 

TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Since the error says `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')`

I decided to verify my column types using `df.dtypes` and the two columns come as the following:

```
column1                  object
column2                  object
```

Could my error be happening because I need to convert the columns to type int? Any insights on what could be causing the error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. In case it is needed, I had read my data frame using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('quartiles.csv',skipinitialspace = True)
```

Again, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Either the `NaN`'s are strings or the *numbers* are actually strings. `.read_csv()` should have read the numbers as numbers.  Please post a few lines of the csv file. ... [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, based on the error message you showed, there is some string hidden somewhere within your dataframe. So that needs to be removed before the data is to be used. To see which columns:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

If you see `object` for any of the columns, you will know that it is where the string is hidden. It might be good to try and find where that is to understand why it might not have converted properly. To convert all columns to the proper format:

```
cols = df.columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
```

After this, you can perform the operation as you have it now, or to make it simpler to read:

```
df['column3'] = df[column2] - df[column1]
```

A more efficient alternative to converting data formats, as suggested below, is to define the data types as you read in the csv:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=np.float64)
```

For dtype, you can also use a dictionary defining the type of each column, if they need to be different. If there is an error when reading in the csv, you may need to set the parameter error_bad_lines to False. If you still run into problems, though, you may have to stick with reading it in as is and then converting data formats.

Comment: Might be better to *solve the problem* when the csv is read into a DataFrame instead of doing it after the fact.

Comment: Great suggestion wwii, just added info on how to do that.